# Spring @EnableSpringConfigured not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I try to use @EnableSpringConfigured, but it is not work.

Engine.java

```
@Component
public class Engine {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Engine run");
    }
}
```

Entity.java

```
@Component
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
public class Entity {

    @Autowired
    private Engine engine;

    public void exec() {
        if (engine != null)
            engine.run();
        else
            System.out.println("exec failure");
    }

}
```

EntityBuilder.java

```
@Component
public class EntityBuilder {

    public Entity create() {
        return new Entity();
    }
}
```

EntityApplication.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class EntityApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(EntityApplication.class);
        EntityBuilder builder = context.getBean(EntityBuilder.class);
        builder.create().exec();
    }
}
```

The above four java in same package, I try run EntityApplication.java and expect to see "Engine run", but actual result always is "exec failure".

---

help! code is in https://github.com/lemonguge/spring/tree/master/spring-core/spring-aspect/src/main/java/cn/homjie/spring/aspect/newx

Comment: what is the exception you are getting

Comment: no exception, just out "exec failure" @Arun Kumar Mudraboyina

Comment: which spring version you are using

Comment: Spring version is 4.3.11.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring can configure objects only if load time waving is enabled. You should mark your configuration with `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` annotation

You need either load-time weaving or compile time weaving for the Configurable annotation

Comment: But i used @EnableSpringConfigured annotation, the support is intended to be used for objects created outside of the control of any container.  so when i new a  object, it should be aop and autowired.

Answer (score 1):

You declared Entity as a spring component, but inside EntityBuilder create()method, you manually creating Entity instance which means you
are not using Entity object which is created by spring container.
So how can spring auto wires Engine instance into your own Entity instance.
Reason why every time `if (engine != null)` becoming false. 
If you declared your classes as spring components,  spring container creates
the instances for them and we need to us them inorder to get the proper wiring system. Dont create your own instances if those classes connected with wiring.

Comment: But i used @EnableSpringConfigured annotation, the support is intended to be used for objects created outside of the control of any container.  so when i new a  object, it should be aop and autowired.